# R Import files with differing number of initial rows to skip

Tags: r, for-loop, import, skip

I need to read many files into R, do some clean up, and then combine them into one data frame.  The files all basically start like this:

```
=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log 2016.07.11 09:47:35 =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=
up
Upload #18
Reader: S1  Site: AA
--------- upload 18 start ---------
Type,Date,Time,Duration,Type,Tag ID,Ant,Count,Gap
E,2016-07-05,11:45:44.17,"upload 17 complete"
D,2016-07-05,11:46:24.69,00:00:00.87,HA,900_226000745055,A2,8,1102
D,2016-07-05,11:46:43.23,00:00:01.12,HA,900_226000745055,A2,10,143
```

The row with column headers is `"Type,Date,Time,Duration,Type,Tag ID,Ant,Count,Gap"`.  Data should have 9 columns. The problem is that the number of rows above the header string is different for every file, so I cannot simply use skip = 5. I also only need lines that begin with `"D,"`, everything else is messages, not data.

What is the best way to read in my files, ensuring that I have 9 columns and skipping all the junk?
I have been using the `read_csv` function from the `readr()` package because thus far it has produced the fewest formatting issues.  But, I am open to any new ideas including a way to read in just lines that begin with `"D,"`.  I toyed with using `read.table` and `skip = grep("Type," readLines(i))`, but it doesn't seem to find the header string correctly. Here's my basic code:

```
dataFiles <- Sys.glob("*.*")
datalist <- list()
for (i in dataFiles) {
 d01 <- read_csv(i, col_names = F, na = "NA", skip = 35)  
 # do clean-up stuff
 datalist[[i]] <- d 
}
```

Comment: Is the value `d` in the `type` column consistently?

Comment: Can you rework your question with reproducible data so others can test it out? In principle you are on the right path as this is a problem that can be addressed by reading in a subset of your data (use the `n_max` parameter in `read_csv`) as temp data and using a grep to store the index for the appropriate number of rows to skip for each data file.

Comment: Yes @D.sen, `D` is always in the `Type` column.

Comment: Looks like there are sometimes lines above the header row in my file that read `"Type 'HE' for help"`. This is causing any solution searching for `"Type"` to fail. Can anyone tell me the correct regular expression to search for rows that contain only the word "Type" and no other characters? @D.sen, @bmosov01, @You-leee?

Comment: How about including the `,` like You-leee did in their `grep`. I.e `Type,`?

Comment: @D.sen The file is comma separated, so when I use read.csv () as in your function, the commas are eliminated from the header row and are no longer "available" to read as text by grep.

Comment: Ahh ok, well what about `"^Type$"`, which will take values that ONLY have the word Type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One other basic R solution is the following: You read in the file by lines, get the indices of rows, that begin with "D" and the header row. After, you simply split these lines by "," and put it in a data.frame and assign the names from the header row to it.

```
lines <- readLines(i)
dataRows <- grep("^D,", lines)

names <- unlist(strsplit(lines[grep("Type,", lines)], split = ","))

data <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(strsplit(lines[dataRows], ",")), nrow = length(dataRows), byrow=T))
names(data) <- names
```

Output:

```
    Type       Date        Time    Duration Type           Tag ID Ant Count  Gap
1      D 2016-07-05 11:46:24.69 00:00:00.87   HA 900_226000745055  A2     8 1102
2      D 2016-07-05 11:46:43.23 00:00:01.12   HA 900_226000745055  A2    10  143
```

Comment: This was the cleanest, easiest solution because of unexpected strange formatting issues. Thanks to bmosov01 and D.sen for their useful options.

Answer (score 1):

If your header row always begins with the word `Type`, you can simply omit the `skip` option from your initial read, and then remove any rows before the header row. Here's some code to get you started (not tested):

```
dataFiles <- Sys.glob("*.*")
datalist <- list()
for (i in dataFiles) {
 d01 <- read_csv(i, col_names = F, na = "NA")
 headerRow <- which( d01[,1] == 'Type' )
 d01 <- d01[headerRow+1,] # This keeps all rows after the header row.  
 # do clean-up stuff
 datalist[[i]] <- d 
}
```

If you want to keep the header, you can use:

```
for (i in dataFiles) {
 d01 <- read_csv(i, col_names = F, na = "NA")
 headerRow <- which( d01[,1] == 'Type' )
 d01 <- d01[headerRow+1,]  # This keeps all rows after the header row.
 header <- d01[headerRow,] # Get names from header row.
 setNames( d01, header )   # Assign names.
 # do clean-up stuff
 datalist[[i]] <- d 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom function to loop over each file and filter only those which start with `D` in the `type` column and bind them all together at the end. Drop the `bind_rows` if you want them as separate lists.

```
load_data <-function(path) {
  require(dplyr)
  setwd(path)
  files <- dir()
  read_files <- function(x) {
    data_file <- read.csv(paste(path, "/", x, ".csv", sep = ""), stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings=c("","NA"))
    row.number <- grep("^Type$", data_file[,1])
    colnames(data_file) <- data_file[row.number,]
    data_file <- data_file[-c(1:row.number+1),]
    data_file <- data_file %>%
      filter(grepl("^D", Type))
    return(data_file)
  }
  data <- lapply(files, read_files)
}

list_of_file <- bind_rows(load_data("YOUR_FOLDER_PATH"))
```