# Need to skip different number of rows in R

Tags: r, split, data.table, grepl, skip

I am using the following code for processing my data but lately I realized that using skip = 27 (to skip the information stored in my files before the data starts, is not a good option because the number of rows to skip is different in each file. My goal is to read various txt files (not all files have same no.of columns, sequence of columns vary in files and fix the name of column for temperature) which are stored in multiple folders. My data appears as follows:

```
/* DATA DESCRIPTION:
Algorithm
Checks
    Version 
Parameter(s)
  Date/Time
  Pres
  Wind
  ...
  ...
*/
Date/Time Pres Wind Temp
2022-03-01S01:00:00 278 23 29
2022-03-01S02:00:00 278 23 23
..
```

I want to read my data from the line next to */ To do it, I tried code [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46223063/r-import-files-with-differing-number-of-initial-rows-to-skip) but I am not able to rewrite it as per my requirement. Could anyone please help me in modifying the code accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example, it looks like the first line you want to read starts with `Date/Time`.

From the `?fread` documentation, `skip` can be:

> ... `skip="string"` searches for `"string"` in the file (e.g. a substring of the column names row) and starts on that line (inspired by `read.xls` in package `gdata`).

Using that, I would think you can do

```
dt <- lapply(filelist, fread, skip = "Date/Time")
```

---

Since that doesn't work in this case, here's an adaptation where we look for the last comment line and set the `skip` parameter accordingly, as in the answer you link in your question:

```
dt <- lapply(filelist, function(file) {
  lines <- readLines(file)
  comment_end = match("*/", lines)
  fread(file, skip = comment_end)
})
```

If your files are very long and you can set an upper boundary on the length of the comment, you could make this much more efficient by setting a max number of lines to read in `readLines`, e.g., `lines <- readLines(file, n = 100)` to read at most 100 lines to look for the comment. If you want to be really fancy, you could check the first 100 lines, and if you still don't find then try again reading the whole file.

This also assumes the last comment line is exactly "*/". If there is the possibility of whitespace or other characters on that line, you could replace `match("*/", lines)` with `grep("*/", lines, fixed = TRUE)[1]`, which will be a little bit slower.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, you understood it correctly. I want to start reading from Date/Time.  Unfortunately Date/Time also appear in the initial few lines which I want to skip, so I am afraid that using skip="Date/Time" may not work the way we are expecting. Could you please suggest an alternate solution.

Comment: Perhaps you could be even more specific than `"Date/Time"`, maybe `skip = "Date/Time  Pres  Wind  Temp"` (making sure you get the separator correct, can't tell if it's spaces or tabs or what...)

Comment: I have very strange set of data and your solution is not possible because the sequence of columns vary in files. The only thing that can work for my files is to start read the line next to */

Comment: @AlexiakBoston, see my alternative approach below. But first I'd check the first suggested solution, i.e. removing the `skip` parameter at all.

Comment: That's too bad, this would have been a nice simple solution. I'll edit with an adaptation of the answer linked in your question.

Comment: @AlexiakBoston in Your example data values are separated with a single space while headers are separated with two space characters. Is it the actual structure of Your data or an unintended mistake?

Comment: @JakubMałecki I think comments like this (questions for OP) are more appropriate on the question than on this answer.

Comment: @AlexiakBoston I'd encourage you to try Jakub's first solution, simply omitting the `skip`. It seems like `fread()` is smart enough to handle this on its own.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation of `fread` function, skip parameter (emphasis added):

> `skip`
> If 0 (default) start on the first line and from there finds the first row with a consistent number of columns. This **automatically avoids irregular header information before the column names row**...

So just remove the `skip = 27` from Your `lapply` call:

```
dt <- lapply(filelist, fread)
```

Using the data You provided the result is a list of data table(s):

```
[[1]]
             Date/Time Pres [Pa]   Wind [m/s] Temp....
1: 2022-01-01S00:00:00  278   23 29....    NA       NA
2: 2022-01-01S01:00:00  277   23  28...    NA       NA
3:                   .   NA   NA           NA       NA
4:                   .   NA   NA           NA       NA
```

### Alternative approach

```
library(readr)
bad_data <- readLines("/path/to/the/file.txt")
comment_end <- which(bad_data == "*/") # look for the end of the preamble (comment)
new <- bad_data[-seq_len(comment_end)] # remove all bad elements
new_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".tsv") # store the new content as a temp file
writeLines(as.character(new), con = new_file)
clean <- fread(new_file) # re-read the file
```

Comment: @GregorThomas, it's not stated explicitly. Alexia wrote that she'd like to read the content beginning at the next line after '*/'. Can You guarantee the actual content in all files starts with 'Date/Time'? She wrote "not all files have same no.of columns", so looking exactly for 'Date/Time phrase' may be risky.

Comment: Strong agree - I can't guarantee that but OP hopefully knows and can make the call for themself.

Comment: I hadn't thought to do it, but on OP's example removing the `skip` entirely does work. I'd suggest demonstrating that in your solution so it is clear: `fread(text = "<<OP's example>>")` gives a good result. Demonstrating that will make it clear that your first approach works and keep OP from assuming--as I did--that you were misreading the question.

Comment: Thanks @GregorThomas. The alternative approach using `readLines` suggested by You is much more elegant than mine.

Comment: @JakubMałecki Thanks for your response but your first solution didn't work for me. Without skip, merged returns me output with initial rows which I want to skip.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, `fread` is pretty smart and will omit comments. In your case, the data need a little bit of preprocessing before `fread` can handle it. Basically, we need to delete everything from beginning of the file to `*/`. This can be addressed by utilizing the `cmd` argument of `fread` to run external programs in your system. One common program for this type of tasks is `GNU sed`. You can check by running this command in your R session `system2("sed", "--version")`. The output should provide some info regarding your system's `sed`. If not, you will have to install `sed`. For example, on Windows, you will install [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools43/rtools.html).
Then, you can simply proceed with one line of R code

```r
list_dt <- lapply(filelist, \(x) fread(cmd = paste("sed -z", "'s/^.*\\*\\///'", x))) # change filelist to suit your situation
```

Normally, `sed` works line-by-line. However, `GNU sed` with the [-z option](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Command_002dLine-Options.html#index-_002dz) allows `.` to match newline.
In my experience, investing time in learning regular expression and essential Unix/GNU Linux program like `sed`/`awk` is better than trying to do this entirely in R.