# How to read and process the files iteratively through different directories?

Tags: r, dplyr, iteration, tidyr, lubridate

I have using a code (mentioned below) in R to ungz the files and process the files as per my requirement. The code is working well for small number of files but as my data is really huge, therefore instead of reading all the files in one go, I want to iterate through city directories.

Could anyone please help me in modifying the code to run it iteratively through city directories.

```
setwd("C:/Users/Alexia/Desktop/Data/Test_Gz")
#1. UNGZ the files
decompress <- function(file, dest = sub("\\.gz$", "", file)) {
  # Set up source and destination connections
  src <- gzfile(file, "rb")
  on.exit(close(src), add = TRUE)
  dst <- file(dest, "wb")
  on.exit(close(dst), add = TRUE)

  # Copy decompressed contents from source to destination
  BATCH_SIZE <- 10 * 1024^2
  repeat {
    bytes <- readBin(src, raw(), BATCH_SIZE)
    if (length(bytes) != 0) {
      writeBin(bytes, dst)
    } else {
      break
    }
  }

  invisible(dest)
}

files <- list.files(pattern = "*.gz", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
for (file in files) {
  decompress(file)
}

#2. FIXING COLUMN ISSUES
library(data.table)

#List of files
filelist <- list.files("C:/Users/Alexia/Desktop/Data/Test_Gz/", full.names = TRUE, recursive 
                   = TRUE, pattern = ".txt$")

#Read the files
dt <- lapply(filelist, function(file) {
  lines <- readLines(file)
  comment_end = match("*/", lines)
  fread(file, skip = comment_end)
})

#Adjust Column names
dt.tidied <- lapply(dt, FUN = function(x){
  #adjust ? to degree
  setnames(x, old = "T2 [?C]", new = "T2 [°C]", skip_absent = TRUE)

  colnames(x) <- gsub("\\[", "(", colnames(x))
  colnames(x) <- gsub("\\]", ")", colnames(x))

  #return
  return(x)
})

#bind, filling missing columns to NA
merged <- rbindlist(dt.tidied, fill = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)

#3. CALC 15ROW MEAN
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
mn <- merged %>% separate(`Date/Time`, into = c("Date", "Time"), sep = "T")
mnf <- mn %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  group_by(group = as.integer(gl(n(), 15, n()))) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ if(mean(is.na(.x)) > 0.5) NA else mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE)))
write.csv(mnf, 'C:/Users/Alexia/Desktop/Data/Test_Gz/Mean_15.csv')
```

For more information, the sequence of files is as follows:

```
WorkingDirectory
 DET (City A)
  DET_2022_02_01.txt.gz                  #It is monthly file containing per minute data
  DET_2021_12_01.txt.gz                  #There are missing files
  DET_2021_11_01.txt.gz                  #The start and end date of every city differs
  ..
  ..
 MUN (City B)
  MUN_2020_12_01.txt.gz                  
  MUN_2020_11_01.txt.gz
  MUN_2020_08_01.txt.gz
  ..
  ..
```

Comment: In my opinion, you should interactively run your original code and see which step/statements took the most amount of time (e.g., step 1: UNGZ the files or step 2: FIXING COLUMN ISSUES or step 3: CALC 15ROW MEAN, ...) before proceeding with rewrite the entire thing to run by cities.

Comment: I think your "step 2-Read the files" can be sped up quite a bit with my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76296010/9454926)

Comment: An additional step you can take is parallel processing. In `base` R, you can read about it in `?parallel::clusterApply`. For example, you can use `library(parallel); ncores <- detectCores(logical = FALSE); cl <- makePSOCKcluster(ncores); parLapply(cl, files, decompress); stopCluster(cl)` instead of `for (file in files) {decompress(file)}` at the end of your step 1.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a `for`. Something like this:

```
#2. FIXING COLUMN ISSUES
library(data.table)

#List of directories
citylist <- list.dirs("C:/Users/Alexia/Desktop/Data/Test_Gz/")
  
for (citydir in citylist) {

#List of files
filelist <- list.files(citydir, full.names = TRUE, recursive 
                   = TRUE, pattern = ".txt$")

#Read the files
dt <- lapply(filelist, function(file) {
  lines <- readLines(file)
  comment_end = match("*/", lines)
  fread(file, skip = comment_end)
})

#Adjust Column names
dt.tidied <- lapply(dt, FUN = function(x){
  #adjust ? to degree
  setnames(x, old = "T2 [?C]", new = "T2 [°C]", skip_absent = TRUE)

  colnames(x) <- gsub("\\[", "(", colnames(x))
  colnames(x) <- gsub("\\]", ")", colnames(x))

  #return
  return(x)
})

#bind, filling missing columns to NA
merged <- rbindlist(dt.tidied, fill = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but when I am writing merged into a csv after following a code, it is giving me data of only last station. Whereas if I run my code, it writes in csv data of all the stations. I want all data but I want it be to segregated as per city. By the way, what you helped me with is additional thing that I asked for. I need iteration in the second part of my code which includes summarize function.